Deployed application fails to load due to missing satellite assemblies
My Windows Forms app runs fine from VS2022 however when I deploy the app I get the following error on the deployed machine and the app closes:

The *.resorces.dll file is not apparently generated during the VS build process, at least I can't find it.
Either how do I generate the resources.dll file so that I can then deploy it or (preferably) have the resources embedded in the app.
The Resources.resx properties are:
Build Aaction: Embedded Resource
Copy to ...: Do not copy
Custom Tool: ResxFileCodeGenerator
Namespace: Empty
File Name: Resources.resx
FullPath: ..\..\..\Properties\Resources.resx


what are you configuration settings when building ?

@j-memisevic I've edited my question to include same.

what happens if you change to copy if newer for "copy to"

To resolve the issue, you could ensure that all resources are correctly embedded or included in your deployment package.
1.Ensure Resources are Embedded
Open the Properties of your .resx file:
Locate your Resources.resx file, which is typically found under the Properties folder.
Right-click on Resources.resx and select Properties.
In the Properties window, ensure that Build Action is set to Embedded Resource.
Ensure Copy to Output Directory is set to Do not copy (since we are embedding the resource).
2.Check the Resource File's Custom Tool
Open the .resx file Properties:
try to set the value of Custom Tool to ResXFileCodeGenerator.
3.Clean and Rebuild the Solution
Go to Build >Clean Solution in Visual Studio.
Go to Build>Rebuild Solution.
4.Verify the Deployment Package
Make sure that the necessary resource files are included in the deployment package. If you are using ClickOnce, MSI, or another deployment method, verify the content of the deployment package.
5.Handle Missing Resource Files Manually
If the resources are not embedded correctly, you might need to include the generated .resources.dll files manually.
After building your solution, check the bin directory for any generated .resources.dll files.
These files are typically located in subdirectories corresponding to different cultures (e.g., bin\Debug\fr\YourApp.resources.dll).
Include in Deployment:
Ensure that these files are copied to the appropriate location on the deployed machine.
If necessary, you can manually edit the .csproj file to ensure resources are embedded correctly.
<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Include="Properties\Resources.resx">
    <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
    <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
  </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>

